# Chef Workstation Error Cannot load such file

Tags: chef-infra

I'm running chef 12 Server, Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm adding a workstation (OSX 10.8.5) and when I run knife client list i get the following error.  I successfully setup another mac workstation 10.10.3, and it works fine with the same setup.

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
from /Users/martinadmin/.chef/plugins/knife/lib/idns_util.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
from /Users/martinadmin/.chef/plugins/knife/idns_diff.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:44:in `load'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:44:in `block in load_commands'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:44:in `each'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:44:in `load_commands'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:127:in `load_commands'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:208:in `run'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:142:in `run'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/chefdk/bin/knife:51:in `load'
from /opt/chefdk/bin/knife:51:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the mysql2 gem worked.